# Send Keys with NSIS

Tags: key, nsis, send

How to send control and a keys to select files?

OutFile "test.exe"

!include "MUI2.nsh"

WindowIcon Off

SilentInstall Silent

AutoCloseWindow True

RequestExecutionLevel User

!define VK_CONTROL     0x11

!define KEY_A          0x41

!define keybd_event "!insertmacro macro_keybd_event"

Section

Sleep 500

${keybd_event} ${VK_CONTROL} 1

Sleep 500

${keybd_event} ${KEY_A} 1

SectionEnd

Comment: Select files where? In Explorer? In whatever window is open?

Comment: I apologize for my late reply. Yes, in Explorer. Your script worked perfectly for me. I sincerely thank you and hope that you will always be successful in all stages of life.

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestExecutionLevel User
AutoCloseWindow True

Section
FileOpen $0 "$Temp\NSIS_Test_File.txt" w
FileWrite $0 "Hello$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 "World"
FileClose $0
ExecShell '' "$Temp\NSIS_Test_File.txt"
Sleep 2000 ; Make sure Notepad has time to start so that it gets foreground activated
HideWindow
Sleep 500
Delete "$Temp\NSIS_Test_File.txt"


!define /IfNDef VK_LCONTROL 0xA2
!define /IfNDef KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 2

; Pressing Ctrl+A to select:
System::Call 'USER32::keybd_event(i ${VK_LCONTROL}, i0, i0, p0)'
Sleep 25
System::Call 'USER32::keybd_event(i 0x41, i0, i0, p0)'
Sleep 50
System::Call 'USER32::keybd_event(i 0x41, i0, i ${KEYEVENTF_KEYUP}, p0)'
Sleep 25
System::Call 'USER32::keybd_event(i ${VK_LCONTROL}, i0, i ${KEYEVENTF_KEYUP}, p0)'
SectionEnd
```

This does work for simple cases but will fail if the user is already pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> etc. NSIS is not the best tool for UI Automation. Using something like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is recommended...